# Java Script add class on div between two hours and minutes

Tags: javascript, class, addition

How to add class with js between eg 14.15 and 16.15?
I have something like this:

```js
var currentTime = new Date().getHours();
if (document.body) {
  if (14 <= currentTime && currentTime < 16) {
    var d = document.getElementById("div1");
    d.className += "active";
  } else {

  }
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">

</div>
```

How can I add minutes?

Comment: where are you getting 14.15 and 16.15?

Comment: Just time when show start/end.

Comment: You'd need to get the current minutes and divide it by 60 to get the decimal value in hours. Or just append the number of minutes so `14:30` converts to `14.30` instead of `14.50`

Comment: Why not use `getMinutes()` as well? Are you getting any errors?  Why is your snippet not working?

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean with add class?

Perhaps this is what you are looking for:

```
document.getElementById("MyElement").classList.add('MyClass');
document.getElementById("MyElement").classList.remove('MyClass');
```

Comment: The script I have shows only hours, no minutes. I also need minutes.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMinutes

Comment: this is the right way to add and remove classes from an element

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
var currentTime = new Date();
var currentHour = currentTime.getHours();
var currentMinute = currentTime.getMinutes();

if (
  currentHour >= 14 && currentHour <= 16 &&
  (
    (currentHour == 14 && currentMinute >= 15) ||
    (currentHour == 16 && currentMinute <= 15)
  )
) {
  // it is between 14:15 and 16:15
  var d = document.getElementById("div1");
  d.className += "active";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the js Date object.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

You should use classList attribute of the Element to manage the classes. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

We can use 3 date objects ( I'm sure that shortcuts can be employed to use fewer ). We will use one as "now", one as "today at 14:15:00" and one as "today at 16:15:00".  We can easily test to see if the "now" object is within the bounds of the start and end time objects:

```js
const dateNow = new Date();
const windowStart = new Date();
const windowEnd = new Date();
// this is offset in the sandbox
windowStart.setHours(14, 15, 0);
windowEnd.setHours(16, 15, 0);

// force for debug: un comment to verify the check below
//dateNow.setHours(15,00,00);

//debugging only
console.log(`Start of window is: ${windowStart}`);
console.log(`Now time is: ${dateNow}`);
console.log(`End of window is: ${windowEnd}`);

//check to see if we are within the window of time
if (windowStart <= dateNow && dateNow <= windowEnd) {
  console.log(`we are inside the window`);
  var d = document.getElementById("div1");
  d.classList.add("active");
} else {
  console.log(`we are outside the window`);
}
```